# Why coordinates are saved like "0101000020110F00003CDBA337DCC351C06D37C1374D374840" in db?

Tags: postgresql, geometry, java, well-known-text, hibernate-spatial

On my DB, the data looks like this:

[image]

In the DAO I am executing a query:

```
public Object login(UserEntity user) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("SELECT user FROM UserEntity user " + "WHERE email in (:email) ");

        Query q = em.createQuery(sb.toString());

        q.setParameter("email", user.getEmail());

        UserEntity userFound = new UserEntity();

        try {
             userFound = (UserEntity) q.getSingleResult();
        }catch(NoResultException nre){
        }
        return userFound;

    }
```

But if I try to do inspect over *(UserEntity) q.getSingleResult()* I have an exception (translated from Spanish):

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: the operator does not exist: character varying = bigint
  Hint: Either operator match with the name and the argument´s type.
Could be necessary add explicit type convertions
```

It seems that the reason is that geo data are stored as "0101000020110F00003CDBA337DCC351C06D37C1374D374840" instead of "POINT(238271.194740 5070436.677042)".

Is that normal or there are any method to avoid this?

Comment: which WKTReader are you using?

Comment: This one: com.vividsolutions.jts.io.WKTReader

Comment: You need to rework this question to include a MRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and a description of how you are connecting to the database.

Comment: This is not Well-Known Text (WKT) but a hexadecimal translation of Well-Known Binary (WKB). The column itself is a geometry type, which might not be recordable by your SQL client API. The solution is to use `SELECT ST_AsText(geom) as wkt FROM table`.

Comment: At the end, it was easier than this, just use the type Point in the entity instead of Geometry